# Chat using commands

Tags: python, beginner

I have been learning Python and was trying to make a chat system which can be run by commands. This is my first attempt to write the code. Does this make sense or is it wrong usage of classes?

There is a `User` class which will contain the user of the chat.
The `Message` class is used to send messages and count their length.

```
class User:
   def __init__(self):
        self.users = []

   def add_remove_user(self,input):
        command, name = input[:1], input[1:]

        if command == "+":
            if not name in self.users:
              self.users.append(name)
        elif command == "-":
            if name in self.users:
                self.users.remove(name)


class Message:
    def __init__(self,user):
        self._messages=[]
        self._user=user

    def __parseMessage__(self,message):
        parsedMessage=tuple(message.split(":"))
        return parsedMessage


    def send_message(self,inputMessage):
        user,message = self.__parseMessage__(inputMessage)
        if user in self._user.users:
            self._messages.append(message)

    def sent_messages_count(self):
        count=0
        for message in self._messages:
            count += len(message)

        return count

class MessageClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.user=User()
        self.message=Message(self.user)

    def send(self,inputMessage):
        if inputMessage[0] == "+" or inputMessage[0] == "-":
            self.user.add_remove_user(inputMessage)
        else:
            self.message.send_message(inputMessage)

    def sent_message_length(self):
        return self.message.sent_messages_count()
```

Comment: Which version of Python, and is there some test to run it with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few comments regarding style (mainly based on [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)):

- Use for spaces for each level of indentation
- Use a space around binary operators like `=`
- Use a space after a `,` for an argument
- Do not use the camelCase naming style: `parsedMessage` -> `parsed_message`, `inputMessage` -> `input_message`.
- Try not to use built-in function names (`input`)
- For private methods names use a single underscore (there's a use case for double leading underscore in complex inheritance, but that's not the case here)
- Use `x not in y` instead of `not x in y`
- Write docstrings ([PEP257](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/))

Some other comments:

- Why have an `add_remove_user` method? Having both `add_user` and `remove_user` methods would be more readable.
- For the users you probably want to use a `set`
- Be careful with length `message.split(':')`. You probably want `message.split(':', 1)` to avoid problems with messages that contain colons in them.
- `sent_message_length` and `sent_message_count` don't seem to implement what I would expect from their name
- Use `and` instead of nesting `if` statements. For example, instead of this:

  ```
  if command == "+":
      if not name in self.users:
          self.users.append(name)
  ```

  write this:

  ```
  if command == "+" and name not in self.users:
      self.users.append(name)
  ```

Comment: that is some good point , how about class structure. should user class do the parsing of input message or it should be part of some other class like inputvalidator

Comment: I think there's still some work to be done in the code. In my opinion the classic design is having a client class, a server class, a channel class and a message class. The client objects connect to the server, join one or more channels and send messages through a channel. The server object forwards the messages to all clients connected to a channel. The channel objects might be just a list of users or maybe act as a message queue of pending messages. The message objects might be just containers or do some encoding/decoding.